# Grouping and sorting rows in Excel based on single column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, sorting

I have a list of families I need to sort by last name in column A. You can see that each child in the family has its own row. The problem is that when you apply sort by column A descending, it does not keep families together. Instead, it sorts rows individually, leaving the second and third child in each family (with a blank A column) at the bottom.
[image: THE IMAGE!!!]

I'm looking to group families together, but the Group feature under Data was no help (it kept combining groups of adjacent families). Is there any simple way to do this? I was looking through some other posts and some even suggested VBA macros.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't replicate the data in columns A, B and C down into the blank cells? That is why Excel's sorting isn't doing what you want. If you are bothered about not replicating data in multiple cells you really should be using a database, but for your fairly straightforward requirements I would just fill in the blanks. CTRL+D will make the process a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to add the last name to every row?

Then you could try this method: Select both col A & D, then click Data-Sort and make col A the primary sort and col D the secondary sort.